# Exchange Rate between Ether and Token

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, ether, tokens, dao

Newbie question. On every contract I made, I have ability to create token, which will become 'the money' exchange in my smart contract. What I don't understand is, how to specify exchange rate of my token to Ether? When people want to buy my token, how to specify the amount of ether or money?

Comment: Here is an example https://github.com/TokenMarketNet/ico/blob/master/contracts/FlatPricing.sol#L22

Comment: This functionality can be added in your token contract by checking the `msg.value` field at the time of dispersing tokens.

Comment: Thank you @MikkoOhtamaa. Is that mean that the value is flat, not fluctuated as in ether?

Comment: Yes, that's the simplest pricing model.

Comment: Two main options. 1) A standing offer in your contract. The simplest policy is a peg: "we buy and sell these tokens for one ETH each". 2) Get the token listed on an exchange. Token value is discovered in a bid/ask marketplace. If that sounds interesting, investigate ERC20 standard interface.

Comment: Thank you @RobHitchens, ERC20 looks interesting. Will find out. Our concept is to put DAO token as company share. As the company become profitable, the amount of individual token will automatically raised up as in share.  But its private company, so its not depend on exchange list. 

Could you please put in answer section instead in comment? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two main options.

1. A standing offer in your contract. The simplest policy is a peg: "we
   buy and sell these tokens for one ETH each". It can literally be any policy you can define since it will be enforced by the token contract.
2. Get the token listed on an exchange. Token value is discovered in a
   bid/ask marketplace. If that sounds interesting, investigate ERC20
   standard interface. This is appropriate if the token represents some sort of bearer instrument with "backing" that convincingly gives the holder a claim. Any form of asset, privilege or revenue steam you can code is a candidate for the property that gives the token value. The market will discover the value of a token.

Hope it helps.